# WebRTC Screen Sharing - Few windows go blank intermittently

Tags: webrtc

I implemented  the ShareScreen of Web RTC.
But when "Choose Share Screen" popup opens,few of the windows keep flickering and show blank content (black screen) most of the time. On selecting one of those windows and doing screen share, the peer also gets the same flickering.

Please help. I have attached the image link which shows the problem https://webrtc.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=43840000000&name=Screenshot.png&token=ABZ6GAdcyh_dpvmXdbR02t3LX72wbfE4Qg%3A1425623918522&inline=1

Regards
Raghav

Comment: No I am using some other signalling server. But  just to say only after signalling handshake has been successfully accomplished , I try to do the peer to peer screen share using RTC. It is here where I witness this issue.Also even in this demo https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/ I see the same problem

Comment: Sometimes handshakes may be established, but data have to be transferred for sharing. I guess in your case data is not shared. Did you get the response data well?

Comment: Thanks for the input .Yes, it all is done. Basically with the same handshake I am sharing the user's video from webcam  and send it across which is working fine. Also, the point I want to make is this happens   before initiating screen share, I mean the popup where the user is asked to share the screen. There few of the windows keep going blank

Comment: As I said with this demo too https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/  , when I click on share screen I see few of the windows blanked intermittently . Am I missing something

Comment: For screen sharing in webRTC ,we want signaling server(node.js or any) and IceCandidate (STUN,TURN) server do You got it.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ this link will help You for your problem

Comment: Here is the image link which shows the issue https://webrtc.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=43840000000&name=Screenshot.png&token=ABZ6GAdcyh_dpvmXdbR02t3LX72wbfE4Qg%3A1425623918522&inline=1

Answer (score 0):

Please check your signalling server. This error occurs only when something wrong in your signalling server.  Similar kind of error occured to me. I used nodeJS. Sometimes handshakes may be established, but data have to be transferred for sharing.

For instance check whether the request and response is prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the input .Yes, it all is done. Basically with the same handshake I am sharing the user's video from webcam and send it across which is working fine. Also, the point I want to make is this happens before initiating screen share, I mean the popup where the user is asked to share the screen.  
Here is the image link which shows the issue https://webrtc.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=43840000000&name=Screenshot.png&token=ABZ6GAdcyh_dpvmXdbR02t3LX72wbfE4Qg%3A1425623918522&inline=1

Comment: Sorry, The link seems broken

Comment: Did you get any response as stream...? Can you state the response here if any?

Comment: This is another link https://www.dropbox.com/s/89xqhu3xb9w3ivo/Screenshot.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Chrome on Windows:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=613987

Try to migrate to FF or to Linux...